# How to add custom header in angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have added custom Request headers to my $http request.the headers does not show up in the Request, instead its comes under Access-Control-Request-Headers like Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, mobile-access See below the output in chrome's network tab:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,content-type,mobile-access
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Headers` those are server side headers..

Answer (score 0):

The Request that you are looking at, is the OPTIONS request. That is the pre request that some navigators make before make the real request. This request are asking to the server to see if he can to make a petition with the headers authorization,content-type,mobile-access and the method GET. The server must return with the headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,content-type,mobile-access
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:OPTIONS, GET
```

That will tell to the browser that the petition is allowed and he will make the petition.
You can check the console tab and see if is showing an error saying that the request was blocked or something like that.

What are you using in server?

Comment: Actually, In the server, I am checking whether the custom header value is present or not. If its present, i will allow that domain, Otherwise i will reject. This what i did. var domain;  if(req.headers['mobile-access'] !== 'some value' ) {
res.send(401);
        } else {
           domain = req.headers.origin;
        }

Comment: You can't know the value of the header in the preflight request. The browser will only send the value of the header if you allow the petition.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel